# Proof that $ ||f|| = \sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^{n}p(x_k)f(x_k)^2} $ is normed vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I've to prof given $X = \{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\}$ and function $p$ with property $p(x: X) > 0$ that equation $ ||f|| = \sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^{n}p(x_k)f(x_k)^2} $
is norm on discrete set $X$.

This definition is what I need to prove - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space

I've problem with proof for  triangle inequality though.

$$ ||f + g|| \le ||f|| + ||g|| $$

Ok, so I have $||f||+ ||g|| = \sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^{n}p(x_k)f(x_k)^2} + \sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^{n}p(x_k)g(x_k)^2} $

And I have $||f + g|| = \sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^{n}p(x_k)(g(x_k)+f(x_k))^2}$ ? I so then $||f + g|| = \sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^{n}p(x_k)(g(x_k)^2+2g(x_k)f(x_k) + f(x_k)^2)}$ ... I'm too rusty with calculations to finish this.

$ ||f + g|| \le ||f|| + ||g|| $

$$  \sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^{n}p(x_k)(g(x_k)+f(x_k))^2} \le \sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^{n}p(x_k)f(x_k)^2} + \sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^{n}p(x_k)g(x_k)^2}$$

Both sides are higher than 0, so

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n}p(x_k)(g(x_k)+f(x_k))^2 \le \sum_{k=0}^{n}p(x_k)f(x_k)^2 + 2\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^{n}p(x_k)g(x_k)^2f(x_k)^2} + \sum_{k=0}^{n}p(x_k)g(x_k)^2 $$

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n}p(x_k)(g(x_k)+f(x_k))^2 = \sum_{k=0}^{n}p(x_k)g(x_k)^2 + \sum_{k=0}^{n}p(x_k)f(x_k)^2 + 2\sum_{k=0}^{n}p(x_k)f(x_k)g(x_k) $$
So
$$ 2\sum_{k=0}^{n}p(x_k)f(x_k)g(x_k) \le 2\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^{n}p(x_k)g(x_k)^2f(x_k)^2} $$
...

Comment: You talk about a norm on $X$, but this seems to be a norm on the functions of $X$. Could you maybe quote the exact question?

Comment: @JendrikStelzner "Proof that equation [..] is a norm on discrete set X". I've corrected question.

Comment: When you square both sides to remove the square root the mixed term is actually $\sqrt{ \sum_{k,l=1}^n p(x_k) p(x_l) f(x_k)^2 g(x_l)^2 }$. I would also advise you to not edit your question everytime you have done a new step. Instead, think about what exactly you want to know and what you already have and then make clear what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that what you really want is a norm on the realvalued functions on $X$, i.e. $\mathbb{R}^X$. For $f,g \in \mathbb{R}^X$ we can define
$$
 \langle f,g \rangle := \sum_{k=0}^n p(x_k) f(x_k) g(x_k).
$$
Notice that $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle \colon \mathbb{R}^X \times \mathbb{R}^X \to \mathbb{R}$ is a symmetric, positive definite (because $p(x_i) > 0$) bilinear form, i.e. a scalar product. Then the resulting norm $\|\cdot\| = \sqrt{\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle}$ is now given by
$$
 \|f\|
 = \sqrt{\langle f,f \rangle}
 = \sqrt{ \sum_{k=1}^n p(x_k) f(x_k)^2}.
$$